# Broadcast receiver in a Fragment

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a Broadcast receiver in my Fragment, to track any newly received SMS.

```
private BroadcastReceiver smsBroadcastReceiver;
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    smsBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e("smsBroadcastReceiver", "onReceive");
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
super.onStart();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(smsBroadcastReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(smsBroadcastReceiver);
}
```

and the permissions in the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

The problem is I never get the log `Log.e("smsBroadcastReceiver", "onReceive");`
I definitely get the SMS while the receiver is still registered.

However if I write the receiver as a separate class and put it in the Manifest, then it's onReceive() is called.

Did I miss something?

Comment: the answer is correct, this provides better performance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42323093/3923839

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Did I miss something?**

Yeah.. you are missing one point that objects life span. When you register the broadcast receiver in the fragment then the receiver object will alive till the fragment is exist. When the fragment is destroyed then the receiver also unregistered. So whenever the fragment is alive then only you will get the broadcast otherwise it won't work. To receive broadcast when the app is not in the foreground then you have to register the broadcast in the manifest file.

**UPDATE**

try like this

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
private BroadcastReceiver smsBroadcastReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e("smsBroadcastReceiver", "onReceive");
        }
    };
```

And register your receiver like

```
getActivity().registerReceiver(smsBroadcastReceiver, filter);
```

and unregister like

```
getActivity().unregisterReceiver(smsBroadcastReceiver);
```

Comment: I only what the receiver when I am in this Fragment. Hence I didn't register it in Manifest. Also I kept logs in onStart() and onStop() and for sure the sms is received when the receiver is still registered.

Comment: local broadcast receiver basically used for updating ui continuously from receiver,here you can use simple receiver for tracking sms

Comment: Yeah I removed `LocalBroadcastManager` and it works now. Thanks

Comment: Actually I had same issue but I as @Housefly said removing LocalBroadcastManager solved the issue. But I solve have to say that I had in an other app where I used LocalBroadcastManager but the context where it was sent was different which I though was the issue for me.