# How to registerReceiver in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I show Bluetooth devices in a `ListView`. I tried it in an `Activity` before and it worked, but now I have to include this `ListView` in a `Fragment`

It´s clear that one or two things don´t belong here, like the `registerReceiver`, `unregisterReceiver` and `RESULT_CANCELED`.

```
protected void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
     filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
     filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
     filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);


}

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity()     , "El Bluetooth debe estar activado para continuar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    }
```

The lines that start with `registerReceiver`, `unegisterReceiver` and `if(resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED){` are giving me problems.

As an aditional fact, I have tried to to change it to an Activity instead of a Fragment, but my Main class have an error with that because I am working with Fragments.

Comment: Please only include the code *that is relevant to your problem.* This is a huge blob of code, and you seem to only have problems with about three lines of it.

Comment: ok, that´s it, the problem are that three voids

Answer (score 52, accepted):

All these methods and variables belong to `Activity` class. So consider calling them with context of parent Activity of Fragment.

You may call required methods as:

```
 requireActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

and

```
 requireActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```

---

`if(resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED){`

can be replaced with

`if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){`

Hope this solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding to a broadcast message, you won't receive anything if you register like that:

```
getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

You should write either:

`LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(receiver,  filter);`

*For instance, case of an intent sent from a service (IntentService).*

Answer (score 1):

The [`registerReceiver()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter)) and [`unregisterReceiver()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unregisterReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver)) methods are methods of the `Context` class. In this case, you need your `Activity` (which is a `Context`).

Fragments provide easy access to their containing Activity via the [`getActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()) method.

[`RESULT_CANCELED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_CANCELED) is simply a static variable on the `Activity` class, so you can access it anywhere via `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`.

Answer (score 1):

given that activity is recreated in configuration changes while fragment resist, it means activity context might disappear which leads to losing receivers in activity recreation. So I'd suggest to register broadcast receivers in your fragment with application level context. You then may register and unregister your receivers in `onResume()` and `onPause()` of the fragment respectively. This way your receivers are bound to the fragment lifecycle not the activity.